# How to get rid of texture tiling

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm working on a project which has many repeating tiles with the same texture. My problem is is that the textures don't blend together well (See bellow).
[image]

I have tried using World coordinates but I don't really understand them since I am new to Unreal Engine and Niagara system. Here is my current material:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you even want to achieve? Can you give an example of what your desired result looks like? Because tiling textures are everywhere in 3d rendering and I don't see anything bad with having them.

Comment: I would like something similar to what this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUyl2MbcKuE) does where the textures blend together, but since I am not using a landscape, I don't know how I would achieve a similar result.

Comment: What is your desired result? Obviously, this tutorial only works for landscapes, so what do you expect to see when not using landscapes?

Comment: I would want a smooth transition between the textures of the tiles and so that it blends together. Currently the textures look very jarring together because you can see that the texture is just being repeated.

Comment: I do not think what you want is possible without modifying the UVs of your texture targets. They have to be linked together, so macro tiling over them is possible. You could try to use world or screen space information to "fake" this, but I believe this is not worth the hassle. What you are trying to achieve is not done outside of landscapes and even within, I have never seen it being used in a project. There are better ways to "hide" tilable textures than blending them into mush. I don't think I can help you with this. Good luck.